Setting localWorkspaceFolder variable
I run task that shows ${localWorkspaceFolder} variable in Visual Studio Code. Task result shows that ${localWorkspaceFolder} is just empty. Why?
Task output:
Executing task in folder esp32_7: echo Workspace folder: ${localWorkspaceFolder} 

Workspace
folder:
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

Task code:
{
          "label": "Echo Workspace Folder",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "echo Workspace folder: ${localWorkspaceFolder}"
}

This is problem for me, because this variable is used in my ESP32 development docker container. And I'm getting error while reopening in container:
Workspace folder in devcontainer.json must be an absolute path.

Is it possible to set this variable to particular value manually?
Who is responsible on setting this variable in project?
UPD
${workspaceFolder} contains correct path to my project folder while ${localWorkspaceFolder} remains empty.
